# Trigger cheap wireless doorbell

Tags: arduino-uno, library

I would like to trigger a simple wireless doorbell.
The doorbell uses 433Mhz. To read and send signals I am using the FS1000A Set (sender and receiver).

I've started by connecting the receiver to the Arduino and afterwards I uploaded the ReceiveDemo_Advanced (RCSwitch library). If I press the Doorbell Button it ouputs:

```
 Decimal: 1987151315 (32Bit) Binary: 01110110011100011000010111010011 Tri-State: not applicable PulseLength: 708 microseconds Protocol: 2
Raw data: 7272,444,1612,1464,588,1464,588,1464,588,440,1612,1472,568,1476,580,456,1596,452,1600,1476,580,1472,580,1468,584,444,1608,444,1608,448,1608,1464,584,1468,584,448,1608,444,1608,440,1608,448,1604,1472,584,444,1608,1468,584,1464,588,1464,592,440,1612,1464,588,444,1608,440,1612,1464,588,1464,600,

Decimal: 1987151104 (32Bit) Binary: 01110110011100011000010100000000 Tri-State: not applicable PulseLength: 727 microseconds Protocol: 2
Raw data: 7268,448,1604,1472,584,1468,580,1472,584,444,1608,1472,584,1468,588,444,1604,444,1608,1468,584,1472,588,1460,592,436,1616,440,1608,444,1608,1464,592,1464,588,440,1612,440,1612,440,1608,444,1608,1472,584,444,1608,1468,584,1468,588,1464,588,440,1612,1464,592,436,1612,440,1612,1464,592,1460,600,

Decimal: 1987151315 (32Bit) Binary: 01110110011100011000010111010011 Tri-State: not applicable PulseLength: 726 microseconds Protocol: 2
Raw data: 7272,444,1604,1472,584,1468,580,1468,588,444,1608,1468,588,1460,592,440,1612,440,1612,1464,588,1464,592,1460,592,436,1612,440,1616,436,1612,1468,584,1468,584,444,1608,444,1608,444,1608,444,1612,1464,584,444,1608,1468,584,1468,588,1460,588,444,1612,1464,592,436,1608,444,1612,1464,592,1460,600,
```

Now I am trying to send the signal via the FS1000A Set to the "Doorbell Receiver" but nothing happens. I tried it via the Binary send and via the Decimal send method. But the "Doorbell Receiver" remains silent.

Please help me!

Comment: go here https://test.sui.li/oszi/ and paste the raw data .... paste each raw data group separately .... you will see that the second `binary:` does not match

Comment: if you have two arduinos, then transmit the RF code from one arduino and receive on the other arduino .... see if the RF code matches what the doorbell button transmits